# Completion block not being called. How to check validity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, objective-c-blocks

I have this method which takes a block, but that block isn't always called. See the method:

```
- (void)updateWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    [MYObject myMethodWithCompletion:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%s, ERROR not nil", __FUNCTION__);
            completion();
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"%s, calling completion %d", __FUNCTION__, &completion);
        completion();
        NSLog(@"%s, finished completion", __FUNCTION__);
    }];
}
```

I have some more NSLogs inside completion. Sometimes this program counter just blows right past the call to completion() in the code above. I don't see why this would be as the calling code always passes a literal block of code as input.

If you're curious of the output of the line containing the addressof operator, it's always something different, but never 0 or nil.

What would cause completion not to be executed?

Comment: Why are you recursively calling completion?

Comment: How are you confirming that it "just blows right past"?

Comment: Paul.S, I have log statements inside of completion. They are not printing. Completion also does things like hide the pullToRefresh and busy indicator. I put trace statements in when I saw that the PTR and BI were not always being removed.

Comment: Ramy, it's not a recursive call. It's an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that completion was pointing to a different code block than I was expecting. updateWithCompletion was called from viewWillAppear with an empty code block. This is why I wasn't seeing the NSLog statements. Once I saw that I had an empty code block it was obvious how to fix the problem.

Lessons learned: If a code block is nil, the program will crash. This wasn't happening, so that meant that it was calling something other than what I was expecting.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, the program counter blows past the block? Completion blocks are nearly always executed asynchronously. This means that, yes, the program counter will jump from just before the call to `-myMethodWithCompletion:` directly to the end of the method where it returns back to the caller. And then at some point in the future, the completion block will be called.

Comment: Perhaps my words are not clear. What I mean is that the body of completion is not always being executed. I have several pieces of code that use blocks this way and they work great. There's something strange about this particular piece of code. I am looking for a way to check if the block is valid. Something like along the line of respondsToSelector, but for blocks.

Comment: Also, so you understand, I am talking about execution within the block of ^(NSArray *array, NSError *error). That is, I put a breakpoint on the NSLog containing "calling completion", step to the line "completion();", the step in. However it doesn't always step into completion.

I am not talking about the block defined in the function, rather the block of code that is being passed INTO the function.

Comment: @HCHogan: Nothing is wrong with this code. There is no way for a block to be "invalid", unless it's been over-released, and that's just a programming error. The only thing that's close is the block could be `nil`, but in that case trying to call it will segfault your program.

Comment: @HCHogan: Maybe you don't have proper debugging info for the block available, so it can't step in? I think "step in" will only work when you have the source available.

Comment: Kevin, 
Stepping into the code is not really the goal. The point is that the completion block is not actually being called all the time, and I need to figure out why. 

That's why i was printing the address of the block to see if it's nil, but it never is. 

I am sure it's not being released. I'll copy it to the heap as a test just to make sure and release it after it's called.

Comment: @HCHogan: Well if it's not crashing, it's calling *something*. Maybe it's just not calling the block you think it's calling?

Comment: Yes, it is strange that it isn't crashing. Well, I don't know what else it could be calling. There are other classes in my code where I copy the completion block to a member variable so that I can call it in another method, but in this class and method, the completion block is a local and on the stack. I'll try to trap it down further.

Comment: @HCHogan: When the method saves the completion block to call later, it does copy it, right?

Comment: If you are talking about my previous comment, where a block is copied to a member variable, then yes. I use Block_copy and Block_release, which works great. For the function in question, we only need to call the completion in this method, so having it live on the stack should be fine.

Comment: @HCHogan: Completion blocks are usually asynchronous. If it's asynchronous, then it needs to be copied, because that means it lives past the stack. APIs which take blocks and hold onto them for asynchronous execution are expected to copy them, so in this case `-myMethodWithCompletion:` would do the copying. Also, when writing obj-c, you should avoid `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()` and just use `-copy` and `-release` directly. The former don't participate in reference counting, while the latter do.

Comment: Problem found. Yes, completion was indeed pointing to a different block. updateWithCompletion is also called from viewWillAppear, which gets is being called after I pop a view controller off of the vc stack and then execute my pullToRefresh. Easy to fix after I realized what was going on. 
Thank you for your advice about Block_XXXX. I will look into making the change. So, if since copy and release participate in ref counting, I should be able to use copy] autorelease] where appropriate, yes? This will be a bit nicer than balancing release calls.

Comment: In regards to copying completion blocks from the stack to the heap: I was under the impression that the stack is not destroyed until all references are released, thus I wouldn't need to copy my block to the heap if I'm only using it locally in the function. I've never run into a problem using it on the stack so far. There are probably 30 methods thoughout my app that do it that way. Some very short and simple, some very long and complicated. Some use __block vars, some use up to 4 local vars from the stack, some use none (void). I'd like to avoid extra copies if I can.

Comment: @HCHogan: Yes, you can use `[[block copy] autorelease]`. You can also just assign it directly to a `@property (copy)`.

Comment: Yes property copy. I have a hand written setter/getter right now which uses Block_copy. I will be converting shortly. Thanks again.

Comment: @HCHogan: Stack blocks aren't reference-counted. They live as long as the stack frame does. If they're passed to another function/method that will call the block asynchronously, the block needs to be copied, because the whole point of "asynchronous" is "called after the stack has popped". But APIs that run asynchronously like this will typically copy the block for you. You should only need to copy it yourself if you're implementing such an API, or otherwise storing a block somewhere that will live past the current stack frame.